# Scroll to top script - div won't hide when on top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on this website called http://martindue.dk/mmd3x9x/ and I have this scroll to top script that just won't coorporate. I've used the script on many other sites, and it works fine, but on this particular website the div#to-top keeps on re-appearing, even though I'm at the very top of the website, why won't it fade out correctly when at the top?

My code looks like this (the #to-top is insertted after the body-tag in my html):

Javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $toTop = jQuery("#to-top");

    $toTop.hide();

    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).scrollTop() != 0) {
            $toTop.fadeIn();  
        } else {
            $toTop.fadeOut();
        }    
    });

    $toTop.click(function() {
        jQuery("body, html").animate({ scrollTop : 0 }, 500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

CSS

```
#to-top {
    background: url("img/to-top.png") center top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    /*display:none;*/
    /*opacity: 0.0;*/
}
```

I created this fiddle, and here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/2Rubp/

Comment: I took a look at your fiddle code and did not seem to see the problem described.   When I scrolled to the top the little black box faded out and when I scrolled off the top it appeared.

Comment: Yeah, that's the weird part, because it works fine with the fiddle code, but not on my actual website. I guess some sort of other code might be jacking it up?

Comment: Try adding an alert to see if the scroll function is working at all, alert("Scroll Is Working."); below the fade in. If no alert pops up on scroll then you are never getting to the function and it is a problem with your jquery (maybe a missed tag somewhere above it messing witht he code), if it does pop up you must be having trouble finding the div or something

Comment: I tried to alter the code, and remove everything with the fade-function, and instead use CSS within jQuery (opacity 1/0), and now it works... weird

Comment: My last guess is this class .hidden-xs {
display: block !important;
} is messing with it. I put added that in the fiddle and it did screw with it a bit but didn't look like the same problem that you had on your website

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to remove the class from the div, and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is not js but in this case you are only using fading so css can do the trick:

```
#to-top {
background: url("img/to-top.png") center top no-repeat;
background-size: 100%;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
position: fixed;
bottom: 60px;
right: 60px;
cursor: pointer;
**-webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;** 
display: none;
opacity: 0.0;
}
```

NB: this is for chrome see this for cross browser compatibility
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp